# Setting data in state not working in Vue 3 with Vuex 4

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vuex4

I'm learning Vue 3 with Vuex 4 and I'm stucked with something that I'm pretty sure it's simple but I can't see.

In few words, i'm trying to set some data in `state` to have it available to use it in my components but it isn't working.

Let me show you the code:

/// store.js

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios';

const store = createStore({
  state: {
    user: {},
    products: []
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_USER: (state, user) => {
      state.user = user;
    },
    SET_PRODUCTS: (state, products) => {
      state.products = products;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    GET_USER: async function ({ commit }) {
      const user = await axios.get('https://coding-challenge-api.aerolab.co/user/me')
      commit('SET_USER', user)
    },
    GET_PRODUCTS: async function ({ commit }) {
      const products = await axios.get('https://coding-challenge-api.aerolab.co/products')
      commit('SET_PRODUCTS', products)
    },
  }
})

export default store;
```

/// MyComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <div class='bg-aerolab-main'>
    {{ user }} {{ productsTest }}
  </div>
</template>

import { computed } from "vue";
import { useStore } from 'vuex';

export default {
  setup() {
    const store = useStore();
    const user = computed(() => store.state.user);
    const productsTest = computed(() => store.state.products);
    console.log(user);
    console.log(productsTest);

    return {
      user,
      productsTest
    };
  }
}
```

/// main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './index.css'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import store from './store';

const app = createApp(App)
  app.use(VueAxios, axios)
  app.use(store)
  app.mount('#app')
```

Of course the `{{ users }}` and `{{ productsTest }}` bindings are not displaying any data aswell as both console.logs.

PD: I've tried to fetch the data directly in my component and it's working so it's not something related to the data fetched from the API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've to dispatch that actions inside mounted hook :

```
import { computed , onMounted} from "vue";
import { useStore } from 'vuex';

export default{
  setup() {
    const store = useStore();
    const user = computed(() => store.state.user);
    const productsTest = computed(() => store.state.products);
   
  onMounted(()=>{
    store.dispatch('GET_USER');
    store.dispatch('GET_PRODUCTS');
  })
    return {
      user,
      productsTest
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Fetch Data from main.js

I'm sure the selected answer would work properly if you are fetching data from your component(s). However, if you are looking to **Fetch Data from `main.js`** as OP was asking or **`app.js`** if you are using Vue3 with Laravel, you should use `mounted()` in your `createApp()` function.

```
const app = createApp({
    mounted(){
        store.dispatch('YOUR_ACTION') // GET_USER or GET_PRODUCTS in OP's case
    }
});
```

Remember to set up your Vuex store before calling this so the `store` is defined.

### In your components

You can access [the computed state with composition API](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api.html), as shown below:

```
import { computed } from "vue";
import { useStore } from "vuex";

setup() {
        const store = useStore();
       
        return {
            products: computed(() => store.state.YOUR_STATE), 
            //replace YOUR_STATE with your own. In OP's case, it's user or products
        };
    }
```