# Vuex: cannot get store properly initialised

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a vue3 application and try to get vuex 4 up and running.

This is my main.js:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import { Icon } from 'leaflet';
import mitt from 'mitt';
import store from './store';



/* Theme variables */
import './theme/variables.css';

delete Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl;
Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
    iconRetinaUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png'),
    iconUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png'),
    shadowUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png'),
});

export const eventHub = mitt();



const app = createApp(App)
    .use(IonicVue)
    .use(store);

app.mount('#app');
```

My store.js:

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export const store = createStore({
    state() {
        return {
            aantalBankjes: 0
        }
    },

    mutations: {
        vernieuwAantalBankjes(state, n) {
            // mutate state
            state.aantalBankjes = n;
            console.log("Store: vernieuwAantalBankjes");
            console.log(n);
        }
    },

    getters: {
        getAantalBankjes(state) {
            return state.aantalBankjes;
        }
    }
})
```

I then want to use the vuex store in a component. The most important code of this component:

```
<template>
  <div id="myMap" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
</template>

<script>
import L from "leaflet";
import { eventHub } from "../main";
import { Geolocation } from "@capacitor/geolocation";
import icons from "../mixins/icons.js";

const axios = require("axios");

export default {
    

  methods: {
      getBankjes() {
      let vertices = this.calculateRetrievalArea(this.map.getCenter());
      axios
        .get(
          "https://www.evenuitrusten.nl/api/area?lngLow=" +
            vertices.lngLow +
            "&lngHigh=" +
            vertices.lngHigh +
            "&latLow=" +
            vertices.latLow +
            "&latHigh=" +
            vertices.latHigh +
            "&number=200"
        )
        // .get("https://www.evenuitrusten.nl/api/area/test")
        .then((response) => {
          this.bankjes = response.data;
          console.log("Bankjes: axios has returned data");
          this.placeMarkers(this.bankjes);
          this.aantalBankjes=this.bankjes.length;
          console.log("Before commit");
          this.$store.commit('vernieuwAantalBankjes',this.aantalBankjes);
          console.log("After commit");
          return this.bankjes;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          // handle error
          console.log("bankjes:" + error.response);
        });
    },
```

I run into a problem at this.$store.commit. I never reach the line " console.log("After commit");". Instead the catch-function is hit. There is no error message in the console.

What am I doing wrong?

Kind regards,

Hubert

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66845766/setting-data-in-state-not-working-in-vue-3-with-vuex-4/67936190#67936190

It may help you.

Comment: where do you run `this.getBankjes()`?

Comment: The code is part of a vue/ionic application that will run on Android. But currently just in a browser on Windows.

Comment: I will investiagte your link later. Currently found a solution by rearanging one component in the applciation sothat I can pass ata in a slot and don't need the Vuex anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I am new in Vue... but i read that "Mutations Must Be Synchronous"... and you call it in asynchronous code. So, create an action witch will call the mutation and you call the action.

```
actions: {
  act_vernieuwAantalBankjes({commit}, data) {
     commit('vernieuwAantalBankjes',data);
  }
}
```

and call the action in the asynchronous code:
this.$store.dispatch('act_vernieuwAantalBankjes',this.aantalBankjes);